# Compatibility of de Broglie postulate with quantum mechanics and Bohr theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Using de Broglie wavelength we can explain the concept of how the electrons moved around in fixed circular orbits by saying those are the standing waves in which the electron moves around the nucleus in resonant conditions.

However, from my understanding, it is still a concept that is used in modern quantum mechanics. So, in what way does the way the postulate is used to explain phenomena in modern quantum differ from how it was used to explain the Bohr atom?

I'm particularly interested in **how** the application of the de Broglie postulated as an explanation of the circular orbits in which the electrons move was found to be wrong.

---

**Reference:**

This answer was inspired by this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397917/what-is-the-geometry-of-debroglie-standing-waves/397923#397923) on PSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de Broglie hypothesis of matter waves is incompatible with the experimental results, for example, the [double slit single electron at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), where the footprint of the electron is compatible with the point particle axiomatic definition in the standard model of physics, it is not spread out in space. The wave nature appears in the accumulation of electrons.

The Bohr model was good enough before the development of the theory of quantum mechanics with its postulates but was superseded by the solution of the [qm wave equations,](http://230nsc1.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) which gave a lot more verifiable by experiment predictions atomic behavior. There the Bohr orbits become the orbitals, probability loci.

But physics models can still be useful in specific problems, simplifying more complex situations conceptually, so the Bohr model may be still used for rough approximations and the de Broglie wavelength for order of magnitude estimates compatible with both the quantum mechanical and the qualitative hypothesis of matter waves.

Comment: In the post one of the comment is written:
" The de Broglie rule for wave-lengths lives on, but it's application is either in BoTE techniques or buried in the details of full blown quantum pictures (it is most visible in the wave mechanics). –"

This suggests that at least the wavelength part of the matter wave is still used. Now, how is exactly is this part used?

Comment: I thik it is  just as a useful tool as I say in my answer.,  one could interpret the orbital loci as "matterwaves" I suppose, keeping in mind the probability of detecting the matter/pont-particle.

Comment: The point I am stuck on is how they are used useful tools? Initially it was thought that they gave resonant wavelengths for which electron orbits but that is **wrong**, so how was it reinterpreted? However, you have correctly addressed the point in the second part of my question i.e: how it was found to be wrong

Comment: maybe the answers to this question will help?https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=bohr+model+versus+schrodinger+solution+for+hydrogen

Comment: I do have some concept of the Schrodinger model and the Bohr model, however, I just can't understand how a wrong concept in one theory is used again in another theory correctly. Some say that in modern QM it gives the measures at which quantum is applicable, but I'm not sure how that works exactly

Comment: Quantum mechanics is a theory, i.e. it is a self consistent and correct mathematical theory with postulates that define how the mathematical formulae of the theory fit the existing data and **predict** new data. it encompasses in its limits the previous tentative models, as the bohr model, which has some successes. In the same way that special relativity encompasses for small masses and velocities  classical mechnaics: classical mechanics solutions are the easiest for ordinary velocities, one need not use the complicated

Comment: four dimensional special relativity to find  the trajectory of a bullet for example. In the same way the Bohr model can be used when the variables are appropriate

Comment: In my understanding, bohr orbital is incorrect then the debroglie hypothesis would also be as it was used to explain the resonant wavelengths of the orbit. So, if bohr is wrong, then it would be an incorrect explanation to use debroglie wavelength for it, so how was this debroglie concept reinterpretted and reapplied in modern qm

Comment: Both the bohr model and the theory of QM describe the same data. QM is more widespread and describes all the elementary particle data, not only simple atomic physics. In addition at its limits the Bohr conditions  for angular momentum come out in the simple solution of hydrogen. So it is not reapplied  it is normally emergent from the higher theory, at least the anguflar momentum and wavelength conditions ( same frequencies though different interpretation, orbitals instead of orbits)

Comment: Oh, so if I understood it correctly, In bohr, it gave the resonant orbits wavelengths and now in the modern qm it gives the wave length at which orbitals repeat?

Comment: No, the wavelength is the wavelength in the **probability** amplitude ,  the interference appears in the probability, and it is connected with the Bohr wavelength for simple systems like the hydrogen atom. The orbitals are where probably the particle might be measured.

Comment: see the single electron at a time link, where the electrons look random with one measurement, but *all* together have a probable distribution that says"wav e"

Comment: One question, you said where "probability amplitude" repeats  but most orbitals like 1s orbital are standing wave which a probability curve. I don't see anything like repeating

Comment: Take a simple example: How would you "see" experimentally  the 1s orbital? You would have to take a large number of hydrogen atoms the electron not in an excited state , and measure the location, by interacting, with each individual atom. That location would show the orbital 1s  . The mathematical wavefunctions that fit the data have the same frequencies as the bohr  atom, that is the beauty of the QM larger picture, and how we can calculate orbitals  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html